# Angular error with Bootstrap node_module

Tags: angular, sass, compiler-errors, bootstrap-4

When I try to do ng serve I get an error from my node_modules. I think I have dragged a file into another folder which my cause this error, but I don't know how to fix this

[bootstrap node_module error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2m6r.png)

Also in my vendor/_bootstrap-grid.scss This part of the code gets underlined now.

[vendor/_bootstrap-grid.scss issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUrQa.png)

Is there a way to get this working again?

EDIT:

After doing "npm i" it still gives me this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvDcu.png)

Comment: try `npm i node-sass --save`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project Directory
Remove Node_module folder
run **npm i** again and it will fix.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

node_modules folder contains the packages or dependencies that are defined in the package.json file. If any files have been dragged and drop in some other folder that simply means the package is not properly available. To overcome this problem run the following command from the terminal. Run this command from the project directory.

```
npm install
```

It will re-install/update all the packages based on the package.json file and thus the error will be resolved.

Comment: I tried both yarn install and npm install but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder and then run npm install

Comment: It is still giving the error. I don't get any errors after installing the packages but when I try "ng serve" the error comes back

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using in package.json

Comment: I fixed it by copying my src file and re download the boilerplate my teacher provided me. After downloading it, I put in back my src folder and installed all the packages again. Now is seems to work well again